# How do I search for a key:data pair in a folder?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have some batch tests which dump data files of the following format in a folder. Each test dumps 1 file and the file name is a generic serial number. 
I would like to generate a list of all failed log filenames with the Testname.

I can use xargs but unable to print out the Testname. 
Following script dumps every log file, and it's workable though I would like a better solution.

grep 'Fail\|Testname' *.log

Sample File test_0123.log

```
[other log of 20MB]
* Result : Pass/Fail
* Testname : test_example_rsa_key_gen
[other log  and trailer]
```

Comment: Is the log filename the value of the field `Testname`? And what is the `Testcase` in `grep 'Fail\|Testcase' *.log`?

Comment: Is the content of each log file just the two lines with `Result` and `Testname`, or are there more lines?

Comment: That's a typo. Each file contains only one testname and one verdict, but thousands of lines before and after those two lines. This line works now. Thank you. grep -A1 'Fail' *.log | grep 'Testcase'.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0777ne 'if ( /Result : Fail/ and /Testname : (\S+)/ ) { print "filename: $ARGV; testname: $1" }'  *.log
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a Out of memory error with Perl. The log files is double digit MB each. A shell script like grep would be more efficient.

Comment: You don't have double digit MB of memory available?  Use this: `grep -A1 "^..Result : Fail" *.log | grep :..Testname.:`

Comment: Yes I do. But there are thousands of log files. I managed to get it done with this: grep -A1 'Fail' *.log | grep 'Testcase'